# Find indices for a specific time

Tags: matlab, datetime

Lets suppose I have a datetime vector

```
>> t = datetime('now','Format','d-MMM-y HH:mm:ss');
>> t2 = datetime('now','Format','d-MMM-y HH:mm:ss') +5;
>> DV = t:1/288:t2;
```

now I want to ind all the indices which have time between 5:00 and 6:00 is there any elegant way to do it without using a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `datetime` class has "properties", so you can get only the hours from all the data:

```
hours=[DV(:).Hour];
```

Now, you want only the dates that their "Hour" is 5:

```
result=DV(hours==5)
```

Comment: I just realized that , Thankyou so much for the answer